# How sending data to a server TCP in PHP from jQuery and this one this to the client Java?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sockets

I manage to send data for ajax (jquery) to the server TCP who is running for line of commands, but apparently the serveris unable to handle them.

**From this JS/HTML I try to send data to the server.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bloquear").click(function(){
            $.post("http://localhost/proyectodam/app/Lib/ServerSocket.php", {op: 1});
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Server in PHP.**

```
<?php 
namespace proyectodam\Lib;

try{
    set_time_limit(0);
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 5555;
    // Create a TCP Stream socket
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP); // 0 for  SQL_TCP
    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');  //0 for localhost
    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);
    //loop and listen
    while(true){
      /* Accept incoming  requests and handle them as child processes */
      $client = socket_accept($sock);
      //$_SESSION[socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555)] = socket_getpeername($client, AF_INET, 5555);
      // Read the input  from the client – 1024000 bytes
      //$input = socket_read($client, 1024000);
      // from here you need to do your database stuff
      // and handle the response 

       // Display output  back to client
      if(isset($_POST["op"]) && $_POST["op"] == 1){
          $message = $_POST["op"];
          socket_write($client, $message, strlen($message));
        //echo json_encode("si");
      }
      socket_close($client);
    }
    // Close the master sockets
    socket_close($sock);
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

**Client Java.**

```
public class ClienteSocket{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            String op;
            while((op = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(op);
            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How the server intercept the data that come for ajax and once obtained to send to the client Java?